# Casting List<Class> to List<Interface>

Tags: c#, winforms, casting

I have two interfaces. One of them represents a "Presenter" class (MVP pattern). It´s called `IPresenter`.
The other interface represents one of the objects that a concrete Presenter class could return. It´s called `IPresenterElement`. 
This `IPresenter` interface declares the property

```
BindingList<IPresenterElement> SourceList { get; }
```

But when I write that property in a concrete `Presenter` class who manages objects of `People` class (which implementd `IPresenterElement`) as follows

```
BindingList<People> SourceList { get { return peopleList; } }
```

the compiler raises an error, telling that the concrete class don´t implements the interface property. In other words, it cannot take note that People is an `IPresenterElement`.

How can I overcome this situation?

Comment: Show the implementation of the People class

Comment: Mark the anglular brackets as `code` and they won't get eaten..!

Comment: C# support variance only for interfaces and delegates, but not for classes. So, `BindingList<People>` is never will be `BindingList<IPresenterElement>` regardless of relation between `People` and `IPresenterElement`.

Comment: You have to exactly implement an interface, you cannot try to change up the parameter or return types.  However you could make the interface generic and specify that the generic type has to be a `IPresenterElement` then your class can specify `People` for the generic type when it implements the interface.

Comment: @juharr I know that; but the property is referring to an interface. So, I (mistakendly, of course) think if the concrete property referenced a concrete implementation of that interface it will work. I'm not so dumb.

Comment: @PetSerAl See ahead the answer from Zdenëk. The overcome he proposed worked perfectly. So, there is an overcome, and your affirmation is not completely true.

Comment: @marcelo Sorry, but I do not see how answer from Zdeněk Jelínek invalidate my statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to exactly implement an interface, you cannot try to change up the return type.  However you can make your interface generic

```
public interface IPresenter<T> where T: IPresenterElement 
{
    BindingList<T> SourceList { get; }
}
```

And then specify the concrete type when you implement the interface

```
public class PeoplePresenter : IPresenter<People>
{
    public BindingList<People> SourceList { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to make the `IPresenter` interface generic:

```
public interface IPresenter<TPresenterElement> where TPresenterElement : IPresenterElement
{
    BindingList<TPresenterElement> SourceList { get; }

    // ...
}

public class PeoplePresenter : IPresenter<People>
{
    public BindingList<People> SourceList { get; }

    // ...
}
```

The question is whether this really helps. If you'd need the `IPresenter` interface being non generic, there is no way except for just having `BindingList<IPresenterElement>` property on every concrete implementation and handle the synchronization with the real data (e.g. `List<People>`)

Comment: @Zdenëk Jelinek Thank you. I will try your approach